# Mean event time calculation incorrect

Tags: c#, math

I have a program, in which an event happens randomly. I'm trying to write some code to calculate and store the average time it takes for these events to happen. Here is the code I use to calculate the mean:

```
int EventCount = 0;
var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

while(true)
{
    if (EventTriggered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event detected");
        EventCount++;
        s.Stop();
        AverageMS+= s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        AverageMS /= EventCount;
        Console.WriteLine("Current average ms: " + AverageMS);
        s.Restart();
    }
}
```

The supposed average milliseconds it displays look to be closer to the individual times instead of the average.

Here is a sample of 100 events:
http://pastebin.com/cmwQPqfR

Comment: It would be because your formula for calculating the average is just plain wrong.

Comment: Apart from that a `while (true)` loop like this is rather a bad way to go - your CPU must be going nuts.

Comment: And, how does `EventTriggered` get reset?

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code? We would be better able to help if we saw the code you are trying to get the average time of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing the average by the event count, meaning you are dividing over and over again. You need to accumulate the total, then recompute the average each time.

More like this:

```
long TotalMS = 0;
int EventCount = 0;
var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

while(true)
{
    if (EventTriggered)
    {
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Event detected");
        EventCount++;
        TotalMS+= s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        AverageMS = TotalMS / EventCount;
        Console.WriteLine("Current average ms: " + AverageMS);
        s.Restart();
    }
}
```

Note that you should stop your timer before the WriteLine, otherwise you are timing the console operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are wrong. You should keep the count and total elapsed time separately an do the division when you need to. Look at What you are doing if your elapsed times are 1, 3, 5. Clearly the averages should go 1, 2 and 3. What you will get is (EventCount =1; AverageMS = 1). Then you'll get EventCount = 2, AverageMS has 3 added then is divided by 2 so Average is (1+3)/2 = 2. Then EVentCount goes to 3 and Average MS = (2+5)/3 = 2.333 (going wrong now, should be 3). If the next is 3 then the average would be (2.333+3)/4 = 1.3333!.

Just keep the count and running total separate to fix it.